# Subscribe others cases using the first observation

Tags: r

I have the follow data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  a = c(88888, 1, 1, 2, 2), 
  b = letters[1:5]
)
```

The result is:

```
      a b
1 88888 a
2     1 b
3     1 c
4     2 d
5     2 e
```

But, I want this:

```
      a b
1 88888 a
2 88888 b
3 88888 c
4 88888 d
5 88888 e
```

How can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hardcode the entire column as the first value using `$k` and `[n]` where "k" is the column name you are recording and "n" is the element you want to replace the entire vector as.  See the below format.

```
df_1$a <- df_1$a[1]
df_1
```